# Java FX вывести значение из TextField в консоль

Tags: java, javafx

Не пойму почему не работает

```
    public class FXMLDocumentController implements Initializable {
    @FXML
    private Button mainButton; //кнопка для действия
    private TextField TFa; //мое текстовое поле
    @FXML
    private void mainButtonAction(ActionEvent event) {
    String a = TFa.getText(); // строка №37
    System.out.println(a);
     }
   @Override
    public void initialize(URL url, ResourceBundle rb) {
        }
```

FXML код

```
<Button fx:id="mainButton" mnemonicParsing="false" onAction="#mainButtonAction" prefHeight="25.0" prefWidth="116.0" text="Button" GridPane.columnIndex="12" GridPane.columnSpan="2" GridPane.rowIndex="4">
                       <GridPane.margin>
                          <Insets left="5.0" right="5.0" />
                       </GridPane.margin>
                    </Button>
```

Ошибка
 Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
    at jfxgran.FXMLDocumentController.mainButtonAction(FXMLDocumentController.java:37)

Comment: `TFa` не помечен аннотацией `@FXML`.

Comment: да, все правильно. Работает. Спасибо.